# Jest/javascript testing library mock is not firing when clicking on a div onclick on the method that is mocked

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

SETUP:
I am doing an integration test. Have the parent component that brings in two child components. On of the child components has an onClick that calls a method IN that child component file. I export that method, mock it.

ISSUE:
In the test, I am finding the "div" with the onclick, fire an event. But the toHaveBeenCalledOnce is not showing it has been called. The actual method IS called when I fire the event, but the "spyon" is not actually spying it.

Code:

```
// import the the file to be mocked, This is a child component
 import * as ProductList from '../ProductList';

// Mock the exported method that I have OUTSIDE the functional component.
  test('Div click', async () => {
    render(<Products />);
    const divToClickAdd = await screen.findByTestId('item17');
    // this doesn't appear to spyOn it.
    const jsonSpy = jest.spyOn(ProductList, 'myMethodToFireAnAction');

    act(() => user.click(divClick));
    // this fails as it is called 0 times
    // I also added a waitFor thinking it was a timing thing, still didn't work
    await expect(jsonSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
 }
```

CHILD COMPONENT FILE: psuedo code - ProductListing

```
 export const myMethodToFireAnAction = (id) => {
    // do some stuff. If I comment in here, it does fire.
 };
 
// This is the child component. It renders a list of divs that have an onclick calls that
// method above and passes the id.
const ProductListing = (products) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

That inner method is considered implementation details, and we want to avoid testing those. Instead, test what functionality changed for the user by firing that method, e.g. if it introduced a new DOM node, changed a style of an element, etc.

If you really need to test that method, you could pass it as a prop to the component, and in the test you do:

```js
const onClickMock = jest.fn()

render(<Component onClick={onClickMock} />)
    
// fire click event 

expect(onClickMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
```

Comment: I really need to test a route change that would show up in redux via redux-connected-router, but that seems very hard, atm.